# partition codes to many files and call it in GUI matlab

Tags: matlab

i have many codes in my GUI in matlab each part of code implement some action , i need to save this part of code in .mat file and call it in GUI to implement by press botton in GUI interface , how we do that please .

this code is an example i need when i press any bottom this code implement

```
xlswrite(file, {'1'}, sheet1, A1 );
xlswrite(file, {'1'}, sheet1, A2 );
xlswrite(file, {'1'}, sheet1, A3 );
xlswrite(file, {'1'}, sheet1, A4 );
```

Comment: I don't understand please provide a small example to illustrate.

Comment: xlswrite(xls_filename, {'1'}, xls_sheet, file_range );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put each part of code in example.m file and make sure that the first line of code is

```
function y = example(x);
```

That way it can be called into action from any program, function or script, regardless if it is in GUI or not.
to call a function from GUI you will have to take advantage of a "callback" that is a special function that runs whenever you click a button. The easiest way to create a GUI is with Matlab's "guide" (just write "guide" in command window) and then a typical callback function would look like this:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

y = example(7);
```

That means your function "example" will start when you click on the button called "pushbutton1"